# How to get current product from esi request?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, block-cache

I need to specify a ttl for a custom product block to force varnish cache invalidation on it without loosing FPC.
Is there a way to get product (at least the productId) from the ESI request so that I can dynamically rebuild my block according to product attributes ?

Here is my catalog_view_view.xml (working in my theme not a specific module):

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="mytemplate" template="Magento_Catalog::mytemplate.phtml" ttl="100" after="product.info" /> 
</referenceContainer>
```

In my template.phtml the product is always null when the ESI request is made:

`<?php $p = $block->getProduct(); ?>`

the request URI looks like :

`/page_cache/block/esi/blocks/%5B%22mytemplate%22%5D/handles/WyJkZWZhdWx0IiwiY2F0YWxvZ19wcm9kdWN0X3ZpZXciLCJjYXRhbG9nX3Byb2R1Y3Rfdmlld190eXBlX3NpbXBsZSIsIndlbHRwaXhlbF9nb29nbGVjYXJkc19yZW1vdmVfb3BlbmdyYXBoIl0%3D/`

Comment: Is the `handles` parameter on this `page_cache/block/esi` url hashed or something? I thought that was normally a JSON encoded array, like `handles/%5B%22default%22,%22catalog_product_view%22%5D/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do that with Magento's default ESI TTL functionality. You can see in `Magento\PageCache\Observer\ProcessLayoutRenderElement` in the `_wrapEsi()` method that only layout `blocks` and `handles` are passed to the `page_cache/block/esi` URL as parameters. The ESI request is not going to get any of the parent page `GET` context like product ID, etc.

To get this custom product block to cache with a separate TTL than the rest of the Product Detail Page FPC you'll need to either use AJAX, or roll your own ESI include that passes along the product ID.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid to add an ajax request. Adding a param to esi request is a little bit complicated, so I will go with a purge+varnish cache warming at my lowest ttl on product pages. Something like https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3806